# Connecting points by line number and code in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polyline-creation, virtual-layer, points-to-line, geometry-generator

I am looking to connect points with a line using Geometry Generator or Virtual layer. Each point has a unique number, a code and a line number. The goal is to display in QField application the lines according to the points recorded on the field. Someone can help me?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

You could use this expression on a Geometry Generator symbol layer of type `LineString`:

```
with_variable('group', "code"||'_'||"line number",

case
when
    $id = array_min(
              array_agg(
                  $id,
                  group_by:=@group
              )
          )
then  
    make_line(
        array_agg(
            expression:=$geometry,
            group_by:=@group,
            order_by:=$id
        )
    )
end
)
```

Groups are created by concatenating the `"code"`, an underscore, and `"line number"` fields. This value is assigned to a variable for better maintainability.

The `case` statement is to ensure the line is rendered only once per group, rather than once for every point. [See this thread for more details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424686/qgis-geometry-generator-make-line-once-per-grouped-geometries).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using [a Virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers).

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. You may want to add more fields and a unique ID.

```sql
select MakeLine(pt.geometry) as geometry
from myPointLayer pt
group by pt.code, pt."Line num"
```

If the input points are not already ordered by ID, you may have to include a sub-query to sort the points first, then apply `makeLine` on it.

[image]