# How to apply two symbology classifications for macro- and microregions in one layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology

I have one layer with macro-regions and micro-regions attributes and I want to do two symbologies classification for each one. Is that possible?

I want to have this exact symbology, the macro-regions with bigger stroke width and the other one normal, without having to duplicate the layers or create new features in the origin layer.

[image]

[image]

The attribute table looks like this. The macro-regions are represented to the field "batalhao".

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table

Comment: Here is a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275159/displaying-categorised-data-using-qgis/276178#276178) using a virtual layer.

Comment: can't you just make a rule-based symbology with different widths ?

Comment: @BERA I added the attribute table in the post

Comment: @LouisCottereau I tried the merged features symbology with the sub render rule based but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Kasper ok, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an extra symbol layer of Geometry Generator type

[image]

###### Expression

```sql
case
    when
        $id = array_max (   
            array_agg(
                $id,
                group_by:="batalhao"
            )
        )
    then    
        buffer(
            collect(
                $geometry,
                group_by:="batalhao"
            ),
            0   -- the 0 distance buffer is to "dissolve" the collected geometries
        )
end
```

Thanks to the very helpful input from @JGH, the expression could be optimised (using [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426593/128665)). The `case` statement ensures that the collection and buffering only occurs once per macroregion, rather than once for every microregion.

###### Result

[image]

###### Notes

The symbol layer disappears when the canvas is panned or zoomed so that the microregion with the maximum id (per macroregion) is completely off the screen.

[image]

Whereas `array_max` places the macroregion boundary on top of the microregions, using `array_min` in the `when` clause of the `case` statement places the macroregion boundary beneath the microregions. Except for the boundary of the microregion with the minimum id. This is visible when using a light colour for the Geometry Generator stroke.

[image]

Comment: You were faster than me...

Comment: It is slow because the aggregation is computed for every sub-region and displayed stacked on top of each others. To speed it up, one can flag 1 sub-region per higher-region, then conditionally apply the aggregation expression only on the flagged records.

Comment: Thank you, @JGH. I have adapted my answer according to your suggestion (which reminded me of a question of my own from about a year ago year that Babel answered). It works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

You may just add a second symbol layer on top with a geometry generator expression like : `buffer(collect($geometry, "batalhao"),0)` (note that will slow down rendering)

[image]