Using make_line between points in QGIS Geometry Generator
I'm having difficulty with the geometry generator. Here is my very basic code:
make_line( 
    geometry(get_feature('New_scratch_layer_f7ec7875_1bec_46b6_84dd_46bca8f2d978', 'name', 'a')), 
    geometry(get_feature('New_scratch_layer_f7ec7875_1bec_46b6_84dd_46bca8f2d978', 'name', 'b')),
    geometry(get_feature('New_scratch_layer_f7ec7875_1bec_46b6_84dd_46bca8f2d978', 'name', 'c'))
    )

I don't understand why it only draws one line.

Ideally I would like it to draw a line between points grouped by type without the name attribute.
This would be very useful.

See this question and answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/424686/128665

You can use array_agg to create arrays of points grouped by "typ" field and orderer by "name":
make_line( 
    array_agg(expression:=$geometry, group_by:="typ", order_by:="name")
    )


